# Adding rows to a .txt file with 2 tab separated columns

Tags: text, sed

I have a 2 columns (tab separated) .txt file that looks like:

```
1.00  GO:0005789,GO:0016021,GO:0005509,GO:0005506
3.33  GO:0005615,GO:0030325,GO:0009653
1.67  GO:0005615,GO:0030325
26.76 GO:0005737,GO:0003993,GO:0004726,GO:0004725
```

And I want to transform it into a 2 columns .txt file like:

```
1.00 GO:0005789
1.00 GO:0016021
1.00 GO:0005509
1.00 GO:0005506
3.33 GO:0005615
3.33 GO:0030325
3.33 GO:0009653
1.67 GO:0005615
1.67 GO:0030325
26.76 GO:0005737
26.76 GO:0003993
26.76 GO:0004726
26.76 GO:0004725
```

I tried `sed 's/\(^[^,]*\).*/\1/g' <in.txt` but what it does is to delete the GOterms except for the first one in each line. It gives me this:

```
1.00  GO:0005789
3.33  GO:0005615
1.67  GO:0005615
26.76 GO:0005737
```

Any suggestion? Using sed or not, everything is going to be welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `awk` for this:

```
$ cat test.txt
1.00    GO:0005789,GO:0016021,GO:0005509,GO:0005506
3.33    GO:0005615,GO:0030325,GO:0009653
1.67    GO:0005615,GO:0030325
26.76   GO:0005737,GO:0003993,GO:0004726,GO:0004725

$ awk -F'[\t,]' '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1"\t"$i }' test.txt
```

Result:

```
1.00    GO:0005789
1.00    GO:0016021
1.00    GO:0005509
1.00    GO:0005506
3.33    GO:0005615
3.33    GO:0030325
3.33    GO:0009653
1.67    GO:0005615
1.67    GO:0030325
26.76   GO:0005737
26.76   GO:0003993
26.76   GO:0004726
26.76   GO:0004725
```

Explanation

- `-F` sets the delimiters. Two delimiters are given here. One is `\t` and another is `,`
- `NF` tells us the number of fields. We loop from field #2 through as many fields there are. For each field found, we print the first field and current field

Answer (score 2):

Use `awk` for that:

```
awk -F',| +|\t' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){print $1" "$i}}' input.txt
```

Comment: Wait a sec, there is a bug in that!

Comment: What happened here? I posted an answer and noticed this answer immediately after. Where was this answer for 9 minutes? Hmm...

Comment: Probably a browser cache problem?

Comment: -F'[, ]+' will take care of multiple consecutive delimiters

Comment: Yeah, quite likely @hek2mgl

Comment: @Ramana Yeah, that's what I had in mind. I'm actually not sure whether the OP is using tabs or multiple spaces. At least SO made multiple spaces out of it,

Comment: @zedfoxus Don't worry! Yours is good as well (And probably correct if the OP is using tabs, which sounds likely after I thought about it) ( Plus one! )

Comment: @zedfoxus Oh, I remember, that I've posted very fast but realized that a bug was in my solution. Then I've deleted it, fixed it and undeleted it. I didn't had anything bad in mind. but looks like that may have cause the issue..

Comment: @hek2mgl Aha, that could be it! Oh, you are absolutely fine! I end up doing deletes/undeletes sometimes myself as well, and can totally see what happened there. Thank you.